# foo__icontains QuerySet empty when querying for old Google Cloud Datastore records

Tags: google-cloud-storage, djangae

I have a model `Foo` which has a field called `bar`.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.CharField(max_length=70)
```

Given an existing instance of `Foo` whose `bar` field is set to `'qux'`, the following query returns an empty `QuerySet`:

`Foo.objects.filter(bar__icontains="qux")`

However, if I reference/save the previous instance or I create/save a *new* `Foo`, I am able to find it using a similar query.

So, **how can I find old, existing records using `icontains`**?

[Djangae's documentation](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/db_backend/#special-indexes) makes specific reference to using `contains` and `icontains`, but I see no mention of this particular behavior or how to address it. (I do see the index being added to djangaeidx.yaml) I also see nothing in the [Migration](https://djangae.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrations/) documentation which makes me think I need to explicitly add an index or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found in the [0.9.10 migration guide](https://github.com/potatolondon/djangae/blob/master/docs/release_notes/0_9_10.md).

In this situation, you'd need to run something like:

`defer_iteration(Foo.objects.all(), Foo.save, _target="your-new-app-version")`

in order to add the necessary indexes to existing records.

While this worked, it definitely feels heavy handed to me. I'd be happy to hear from anyone else who might have an alternative solution.